# How to get JSON from webView.PostUrl()?

Tags: android, json, webview

How can get json response from webView.postURL(). How can I get json response while directly post data in webview.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private WebView webView;
  String postData = "name=xyz&pass=xyz123";

   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(this.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            return false;
        }
    });

   webView.postUrl("http://10.0.2.2/login.php",EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData,"BASE64"));

}
```

serversidecode--

```
<?php
 print json_encode(
  array(
     'name' =>$_POST['name'],
      'pass'=>$_POST['pass']
       )
 ?>
```

Comment: i edit my code. please help

Comment: Is there any real reason for using webview?

Comment: Yes, because app is based on WebView and need some data for native use about the user who are currently on Webview.

Comment: The webview will display what the server responded.

Comment: In onCreate there is nothing in/on webview when you do this post. So i do not understand your explanation 'the user who are currently on webview'.